# how to get an attr() from a textarea val()

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, attr

I am looking for a way to get attribut from the input of a textarea or an input field.
example:

```
<textarea id="foo">
   <iframe src="bar"></iframe
</textarea>
```

I only wanna get the src param.

Is there a easy way (in JS, jquery or php)?

**So now it works:**

Html:

```
   <textarea id="foo">
</textarea>
<p>push</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('p').click(function(){
var textAreaVal = $('#foo').val();
var getIframeSrcFromTextAreaVal = $($(textAreaVal)).filter('iframe').attr('src');

    alert(getIframeSrcFromTextAreaVal);

})
```

Thx

Comment: Did you notice that your HTML has invalid syntax?

Comment: If you remove the closing from the starting tag, how about : `$($('#foo').text()).attr('src')`

Comment: `<textarea id="foo">
<iframe src="bar"></iframe>
</textarea>` This is the correct format. please check..

Comment: make correct html code, you are using iframe inside textarea. it's crazy!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NqFmK/

Comment: `var attr = $($.trim($('#foo').val())).attr('src');`

Comment: Yes that works! Iam trying to get only the src attr. if someone wants to share a yt video or something else.

Comment: So it does not work correctly: jsfiddle.net/NqFmK/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct way:

```
<textarea id="foo">Hello Baby!!</textarea>

<iframe src="http://www.rediffmail.com" class='iwin'></iframe>
```

Now, if you want to get Textarea attr '**id**' then you can do like this in jQuery:

```
console.log($('#foo').attr('id'));// return element id = foo

console.log($('#foo').html());// return element text = Hello Baby!!

console.log($('#foo').val());// return element text = Hello Baby!!
```

**for iframe**

```
console.log($('iframe').attr('src'));// return element scr = http://www.rediffmail.com 

console.log($('iframe').attr('class'));// return element class = iwin
```

Okay, if you decide to use **iframe inside textarea** (`it's not good practice`) and wanna to get **iframe src attribute** then you can do this like this:

**html code:**

```
<textarea id="foo">
<iframe src="http://www.rediffmail.com" class='iwin'></iframe>
</textarea>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
var textAreaVal = $('#foo').val();
var getIframeSrcFromTextAreaVal = $($(textAreaVal)).filter('iframe').attr('src');
concole.log(getIframeSrcFromTextAreaVal);
```

But, inside you iframe will not work. it will work just like string inside textarea.

[image]

Comment: But the iframe is written in the textarea.

Comment: YES !! IT WORKS !  The thing is i wanna make a way to get just the src to implement it to my own iframe code and add some more attributes to the url. Do you know a better way to get this???  [jsfiddle.net/NqFmK/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/NqFmK/7/)

Comment: Does not work correctly. add the iframe code to the textarea. and then press push. if its allready in the html textarea it works.